# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'id'

Tags: php, pdo

Having a problem with "**SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'id'**" here,

```
<? if (!defined("sKEY")) { exit("Houston, We've Got a Problem"); }
class PDOAct
{
    public $db;
    function __construct()
    {
        try {
            $this->db = new PDO(DBdriver.':host='.DBhost.';dbname='.DBbase, DBuser, DBpass);
            $this->db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            $this->err($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    //
    //
    function select($base, $row, $val, $type)
    {
        try {
            if (isset($row[0]) && isset($val[0]) && isset($type[0]))
            {
                if (isset($base['select']) && $base['select'] != "*")
                {
                    for ($i=0; $i<count($row); $i++)
                    {
                        if ($i < 1)
                        {
                            $q = "SELECT `".$base['select']."` FROM `".$base['table']."` WHERE `".$row[$i]."` = ':".$row[$i]."'";
                        } else {
                            $q = $q." AND `".$row[$i]."` = ':".$row[$i]."'";
                        }
                    }
                } elseif (!isset($base[select]) || $base[select] == "*") {
                    for ($i=0; $i<count($row); $i++)
                    {
                        if ($i < 1)
                        {
                            $q = "SELECT * FROM `".$base['table']."` WHERE `".$row[$i]."` = ':".$row[$i]."'";
                        } else {
                            $q = $q." AND `".$row[$i]."` = ':".$row[$i]."'";
                        }
                    }
                }
            } elseif (!isset($row[0]) && !isset($val[0]) && !isset($type[0])) {
                if ($base['select'] != "" && $base['select'] != "*")
                {
                    $q = "SELECT `".$base['select']."` FROM `".$base['table']."`";
                } elseif ($base['select'] == "" || $base['select'] == "*") {
                    $q = "SELECT * FROM `".$base['table']."`";
                }
            } else {
                exit("Query error!");
            }
            $do = $this->db->prepare($q);
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            $this->err($e->getMessage());
        }
        $arr = array('do' => $do, 'row' => $row, 'val' => $val, 'type' => $type);
        return $arr;
    }
    //
    //
    function insert($base, $row, $val, $type)
    {
        try {
            if (isset($row[0]) && isset($val[0]) && isset($type[0]))
            {
                for ($i=0; $i<=count($row); $i++)
                {
                    if ($i < 1)
                    {
                        $q = "INSERT INTO `".$base['table']."` (`".$row[$i]."`";
                    } elseif ($i == count($row)) {
                        $q = $q.") VALUES (";
                        for ($j=0; $j<=count($row); $j++)
                        {
                            if ($j < 1)
                            {
                                $q = $q."':".$row[$j]."'";
                            } elseif ($j == count($row)) {
                                $q = $q.")";
                            } else {
                                $q = $q.", ':".$row[$j]."'";
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        $q = $q.", `".$row[$i]."`";
                    }
                }
            } else {
                exit("Query error!");
            }
            $do = $this->db->prepare($q);
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            $this->err($e->getMessage());
        }
        $arr = array('do' => $do, 'row' => $row, 'val' => $val, 'type' => $type);
        return $arr;
    }
    //
    //
    function execute($arr)
    {
        $do = $arr['do'];
        $row = $arr['row'];
        $val = $arr['val'];
        $type = $arr['type'];
        try {
            for ($i=0; $i<count($row); $i++)
            {
                $bindrow = ':'.$row[$i];
                $bindtype = "PDO::PARAM_".strtoupper($type[$i]);
                $do->bindValue($bindrow, $val[$i], $bindtype);
            }
            $do->execute();
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            $this->err($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    //
    //
    function err($e)
    {
        file_put_contents('log'.DIR_SEP.'PDOerrors.txt', $e."\n", FILE_APPEND);
        exit("Houston, We've Got a Problem");
    }
}
?>
```

when i try to do insert query like this:

```
$db = new PDOAct;
    $base   = array("table" => "users");
    $row    = array("id",  "login", "pass",  "level", "date",       "name",  "sex", "birth");
    $val    = array( 4,    "Paul",   135246,   2,     "2013-06-22", "Paulio",  1,    "1996-06-25");
    $type   = array("int", "str",   "int",   "int",   "str",        "str",   "int", "str");
    $res = $db->execute($db->insert($base, $row, $val, $type));
    print_r($res);
```

In the table I have two entries with id 0 & 1, so it cannot duplicate id..
So what's the problem?
Thank you!

Comment: Theres no magic here, you are trying to insert a record with id = 0, which already exists and it is a PRIMARY KEY (I bet). Do a var_dump($sql) on every insert and you will see what you are trying to insert.

Comment: VAR_DUMP():

object(PDOStatement)#4 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(164) "INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `login`, `pass`, `level`, `date`, `name`, `sex`, `birth`) VALUES (':id', ':login', ':pass', ':level', ':date', ':name', ':sex', ':birth')" }

Comment: **In the table I have two entries with id 0 & 1, so it cannot duplicate id..
So what's the problem?** that exactly is the problem

Comment: No, dont dump the pdo object, dump the data array... the one containing values

Comment: your insert loop uses $row when it should be using $val i the 2nd for loop

Comment: +1 for using PDO. Regardless of other problems this question might have, that's a step in the right direction that's still missing far too often.

Comment: OMG. Are u really? It saying "Houston, we have a problem" & save in PDOErrors.log this `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'id'` error

Comment: Dagon. no, it should be $row, because it's ":"

Comment: "No, dont dump the pdo object, dump the data array... the one containing values"

Do u mean dump for $row, $val and $type?

Comment: @jorge, what do u mean for $sql?

Comment: arr
["row"]=> array(8) { [0]=> string(2) "id" [1]=> string(5) "login" [2]=> string(4) "pass" [3]=> string(5) "level" [4]=> string(4) "date" [5]=> string(4) "name" [6]=> string(3) "sex" [7]=> string(5) "birth" } ["val"]=> array(8) { [0]=> int(4) [1]=> string(4) "Paul" [2]=> int(135246) [3]=> int(2) [4]=> string(10) "2013-06-22" [5]=> string(5) "Paulio" [6]=> int(1) [7]=> string(10) "1996-06-25" } ["type"]=> array(8) { [0]=> string(3) "int" [1]=> string(3) "str" [2]=> string(3) "int" [3]=> string(3) "int" [4]=> string(3) "str" [5]=> string(3) "str" [6]=> string(3) "int" [7]=> string(3) "str" } }

Comment: All queries are right, but error is still appears..
So it is magic, or please explain where I have an error)

Answer (score 3):

Dunno why noone didn't spotted it yet - usually there are 3 to 5 people around to spot silly basic syntax errors like this. It was clearly seen from the query var_dumped.

One of most essential prepared statements benefits - it does **complete** formatting, not partial one, which is used by PHP folks. So, when using a prepared statement, one don't have to format values manually, to avoid double formatting.

```
$q .= " AND `".$row[$i]."` = :".$row[$i];
```

it have to be.

Please note that your functions are wide open to SQL injection.

Also I find the whole set of functions quite unusable. I have no idea why do you want to tie your hands with such a limited subset of SQL. Why not to write clean pure SQL? Why substitute it with some home-brewed syntax, unreadable by anyone but author?

Also note that all this 'Houston we've got a problem' is completely useless. if you get rid of this try-catch stuff, PHP will do all the job of logging and exiting and telling of the problem and do it way better than your code.

What would I do:

```
$db   = new safeMysql();
$data = array("id" => 4, "login" => "Paul", "pass" => 135246, "level" => 2, 
              "date" => "2013-06-22", "name" => "Paulio",  "sex" => 1, 
              "birth"=> "1996-06-25");
$db->query("INSERT INTO users SET ?u", $data);
```

Look, I keep SQL natural, which makes my queries *flexible*. What if I Will need `INSERT IGNORE`? Or `REPLACE` instead of `INSERT`? With my approach I will just change one word in the query. While you will be in a deep fix. For the SELECT query it would be even more trouble.

Comment: Thank you. But i still have error =(

Comment: you need to remove single quotes around placeholders in ALL your functions

Comment: I need to use PDO. If i could, i prefered pure SQL...
What about 'Houston we've got a problem'? Why try-catch construction is bad, when i use PDO?

Comment: ok. Now i have: VALUES (:id, :login, :pass, :level, :date, :name, :sex, :birth). Error changed to SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound

Comment: 1. PDO **does** use pure SQL but your functions doesn't I'll update my answer to show you what do I mean. 2. try-catch is bad the way you are using it.  if you get rid of this try-catch stuff, PHP will do all the job BETTER

Comment: So it says. You didn't pass no data to execute

Comment: Thank you and one more question: If i use query(), should I use addslashes(), to prevent SQL-Injections?

Comment: nope, you shouldn't if you use query() from safemysql. it's different from PDO. Speaking of PDO, you should never use query() but prepare()/execute() only. By the way, addslashes do not prevent injections anyway

Comment: Strictly speaking, one need to use a solution that allows to put **anything** into query via **placeholder**. PDO doesn't allow it. safeMysql does.

Comment: No problem, I'd be glad to help further. Just google safeMysql, I hope you'll find it useful

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Your answers are always poignant and helpful! Where is `?u` documented? [The PDO manual](http://il1.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) doesn't mention it. Thank you!

Comment: @dotancohen Thank you. As you may notice form the above comments it is my own library built upon mysqli. I am not sure if you want to switch to it from PDO, but for such a case you may find a link in my profile.

Comment: Oh, I see now! I'm really not a fan of PDO wrapping classes (I'll let PDO extending classes slide) but I really do like what you've done with the datatypes. It certainly makes SQL more accessible, which I'm sorry to say that some of my devs need. I'll be evaluating this, at the very least to learn from. Thank you!

Comment: @dotancohen the documentation is scarce, I have to admit. So, feel free to ask any questions you have. You may find my email in the profile info as well (or class comments). Actually you will do me a favor asking, I as need any feedback I can get,